# jQuery fadeout woes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the `keyup` on jQuery, is there a way to check a what textfield **currently** has in it's box?

I mean if the textbox currently **does not** have the word 'apples' then **do** a jQuery function, then if it **does** have the word apples... then do **not** do the jQuery function that happens when 'apples' is not typed.

I hope that made sense. I tried using `CASES` and `keyup` but I couldn't get it to work.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `keyup` and `val()` function after selecting the input:

HTML:

```
<input id="granny_smith"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#granny_smith").keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === "apples") {
        alert("apples");
        // Do apples function
    }
    else {
        // Do !apples function
    }
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/uKnJB/

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking at `input` if you're looking to capture user inputs into a textbox. Although the `input` event has cross-browser compatibility issues, it is better than using the `key*` set of events for this purpose. See AndyE's article on this for more information: http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/09/effectively-detecting-user-input-in-javascript

A simple example of how you would use it is this:

```
$('#text').bind('input', function(){
    if(this.value.indexOf('apples') === -1){
        // Textbox doesn't contain 'apples'
        $('#apples').hide();
    } else {
        $('#apples').show();
    }
});
```

This would check the `value` (the text in the textbox) for a certain string and execute a function based on that. A simple demo of this can be found here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/Xy6Cc/